# How do I use styles and external files in EJS without making it static?

Tags: css, express, ejs

I've been searching for some way to use styles (css) and external files (such as images, or favicons, mainly in the ) tag of an EJS file.

The main solution to this would be to use

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));`

I cannot use that, it make the express project static, and I **need** it to remain dynamic, I need the node capabilities. Unless I'm missing something, somewhere I haven't been able to find a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

The example code you have mentioned in question is incorrect. `express.static()` is not used for loading `views`. Instead it uses for [static files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) such as image, styles, JavaScript, etc. You should have to write something like this in your code.

```js
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

And with this, you can load the static files from `public` folder (but not the view as it reside in `views` folder).

I would suggest you to create a express project using [express-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-generator) and with following command.

```sh
express -e project-name
```

After the `project-name` is created, I would suggest you to check the code of `app.js` file. You'll see the following two lines in `app.js`.

```js
// ...some code.
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

// ...some code.
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

First one is for view templates and second one is for public assets where as you're mixing these two in your example code.